# Where can I view Android xml files (online)?

Tags: android, xml, view

I know where to find the actual Android source for java classes, they can be found on git.
But what happened to the awesome xml files? Those xml files contained style, layout and animation stuff, which is very interesting.

Clicking the "View Source" on the top of this page of this Android class results in git. Obviously.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

But what happens when doing the same on a xml file? Yay, 404!
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

So Im asking: Where can I view those loved xml files online or download the current version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what happened to the awesome xml files? Those xml files contained style, layout and animation stuff, which is very interesting.

They are in the git repos. Some are in your hard drive right now.

> Clicking the "View Source" on the top of this page of this Android class results in git.

Only if you have installed [the Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin), AFAIK.

(mentioned here for anyone else that wanders by this question and wonders what the heck you are talking about)

> But what happens when doing the same on a xml file? Yay, 404! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

That is not an XML file. That is a Java class.

The fact that View Source resolves to a 404 may be a bug in the Chrome extension, or perhaps it was skipped because looking at `R.java` would be pointless, since all it has is a bunch of numeric constants. If it used to go someplace else before the kernel.org hack, then it's more likely to be a bug in the extension, but I never tried View Source on an `R.` class.

> Where can I view those loved xml files online or download the current version?

The full Android open source tree is [available for download](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).

There are [a series of GitHub repos](https://github.com/android) that mirror the AOSP projects, since GitWeb was never restored [after the  kernel.org hack. The repo that contains the Android SDK and related framework files is `platform_frameworks_base`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base).

On your hard drive, go to `$SDK/platforms/$API/data/res/`, where `$SDK` is wherever you installed the Android SDK and `$API` is a directory for an API level (e.g., `android-11`). This contains all sorts of resources, some of which are XML files.

Whether any of these are the ones you "loved" is impossible to answer, since we do not know which ones you loved.